# How can I overwrite the first part of a struct in memory with a pointer?

Tags: c

I have a memory address of the start of a number of structs, but need to eliminate some from my output. I think the memory space would look something like

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|      struct      |     struct       |     struct       |
|  linux_dirent64{ |  linux_dirent64{ |  linux_dirent64{ |
|      first}      |     second}      |     third}       |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
                    |*p|-------------->| |
```

As I'm iterating through each struct and returning some data in it, there may be one I need to skip. Would overwriting the first part of the struct with a pointer to the next give me the result I'm after? If so, how do I do that? And if not, how should I approach this?

I know there would be an easier solution if I modified the struct to include what I needed, but unfortunately it's not an option as it's part of the Linux Kernel.

Thanks for any replies.

EDIT: As everyone is interested, I'm filtering the structs based on filename. At the moment, I'm literally overwriting the d_name part with O's so it isn't returned by a system call. However this causes different problems depending on which application issues the system call so I need a more thorough way of getting rid of an instance of the struct.

I've since come up with the following, however it gets killed by the kernel if the d_name test returns true.

```
while(pos < length){
    printk("d_name = %s\t| pos = %i\t| d_reclen = %i\t| st = %i|\n", dirent->d_name, pos, dirent->d_reclen, st);
    if((st = strcmp(dirent->d_name, "testFile")) == 0){
        printk("Out of context file %s\n", dirent->d_name);
        posOverwrite = pos;
        size = dirent->d_reclen;
        while(posOverwrite < length){
            struct linux_dirent64 *next = (struct linux_dirent64 *)(pos + dirent->d_reclen);
            memcpy(dirent, next, sizeof(next));
            dirent = next;
            next = next + next->d_reclen;
        }
        dirent = (struct linux_dirent64 *) pos;
        continue;
    }
    pos = pos + dirent->d_reclen; //Push our position along according to the size of the dirent
    dirent = (struct linux_dirent64 *) (p+pos); //point our dirent to the next calculated system dirent
}
```

In the end I solved this by creating the new memory buffer, and copying all the structs I needed to the new buffer, leaving out any I didn't based on the d_name test. After I'd gone through the whole list, I then memcpy over my entire new list. Thanks for all the help guys :)

Comment: Are you sure that the memory is contiguous?  How are you obtaining the memory?  We need to see the data structure you are using to be able to answer this question.

Comment: I see. After trying your method I've realised each struct is not of fixed size, which makes shifting them all towards the start more tricky.The struct definition is fairly close to what Eli mentions below, d_reclen varies (the length). I have a pointer to the start of the memory space which contains the multiple structs, from that I need to filter some out.

Comment: So you have a chunk of memory, and a bunch of pointers in that memory that refer to various `struct` members?  You are going to do a lot of unaligned memory access then.  Can you show us your memory allocation function?  What is the type of `posOverwrite` and `pos`?

Comment: They are integers. I've no memory management as I'm just receiving a pointer to the start of the memory address from the Kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "may be one I need to skip"? I'm assuming you have an array of structs, and there are some elements of this array you want to remove?

Arrays have to be contiguous. So, generally, there are two ways to do this - depending on how your code is structured one or the other may be easier.

1. Swap the element you want to eliminate with the first element in the array, then increment the pointer to the first element in the array, and decrement the count of elements in the array
2. Swap the element you want to eliminate with the last element in the array, then decrement the count of elements in the array

Of course, this is for appearances only. Don't let these pointer operations mess up your memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some untested code modeled after [remove_if](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove_if.html) from C++:

```
typedef struct linux_dirent64 dirent;

/* example predicate function - modify as needed */
/* returns nonzero if the file should be filtered out */
int has_foo_prefix(const dirent* ent)
{
  return !strncmp(ent->d_name, "foo", 3);
}

/* given a predicate, moves "good" entries to front, returns new end */
typedef int (*predicate)(const dirent*);
dirent* filter(dirent* array, dirent* end, predicate pred)
{
  for (dirent* slow = array, fast = array; fast < end; fast++) {
    if (!pred(*fast)) { /* keep this entry */
      if (fast != slow) { /* need to move this entry forward */
        memcpy(slow, fast, sizeof(dirent));
      }
      slow++;
    }
  }
  return slow;
}

/* example call */
dirent* array = ..., end = ...;
end = filter(array, end, has_foo_prefix);
```

The idea is that the unwanted elements of the array are overwritten step by step with the wanted ones, leaving only the wanted ones at the front of the array, which then effectively has a new (usually smaller) size.  It's O(n) and does minimal allocation.

There is one important bug in my code which I'm leaving unaddressed for now: the variable length nature of the array elements.  If a longer element needs to replace a shorter one, this is a problem.  And in any case the code I wrote needs more pointer-twiddling to advance through the array correctly, but I'm leaving it as-is to be built upon.  I'll note that as you advance through the array and skip some elements, you will see this problem less and less because of the extra space given by the "bad" elements.  So the running time may not be worse than in the simplistic version unless the input is pathological.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing things here -- you essentially have an array of fixed-size structs; you can't really turn that into a linked-list type structure in-place.  To do what you want to do, each time you find one to remove, you will have to copy the rest of the list into the previous position.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe doesn't make sense.

In which structs would you do the overwrite of the pointer? Must be something making them special - can't you use the same specialty for just skipping them in the loop?

```
struct linux_dirent {
    unsigned long   d_ino;
    unsigned long   d_off;
    unsigned short  d_reclen;
    char        d_name[1];
};
```

Are you skipping some `d_ino`? Which ones?

Comment: I'm skipping them based on the d_name. I need to get rid of the struct instance from the memory space altogether really so I can't just skip it in the loop.

Comment: @cheesysam: why do you need to get rid of it altogether? Maybe you can just write it over with the next struct? I.e. if you have XYZW and need to get rid of Y, just write ZW over YZ and get XZWW - you get W twice though, but since you've removed one, you can iterate once less

Comment: As it's a system call, the calling application will be reading this memory space to see what files are available. If I had one twice, it would display it twice, and get confused. I need to modify the memory space, just leaving out an iteration wouldn't work as far as I know.

Comment: Where did this array come from in the kernel?  Wouldn't it be better not to generate the ones you don't want in the first place?

Comment: I'm intercepting the getdents64 syscall. I think not generating them in the first place would make this a lot deeper than it is currently. All I have to do is modify a piece of memory. Trying to hide inodes at the kernel level would probably be a nightmare.